# Absolutely continuous measure which is not equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does there exist a simple example of a probability measure on $[0,1]$ such that ${\rm spt}\,\mu = [0,1]$ and $\mu \ll \mathcal{L}$ but $\mathcal{L} \not\ll \mu$? Here $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at the inverse of $x \mapsto \mu[0,x]$ which is strictly increasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be  a fat  Cantor set and $\mu (E)=\mathcal L (E\setminus C)$. Then $\mu$ has full support (since $C$ has no interior) and it is absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure but $\mu (C)=0$ whereas Lebesgue measure of $C$ is  $>0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich OP wants support of $\mu$ to be $[0,1]$. In your case the support is $[\frac1  2, 1]$.